# Set Animation to Linear layout of next activity?

Tags: android, animation

Is it possible to slide down the linear layout of next activity on splash screen or current activity using animation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all splash screen on Android application is a bad idea. It's an iOS thing that even there most of the time is not required.

That being said - I recommend this tutorial [tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

[Activity animation Google tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes if course it is and it is simple.

Just Use google transition api for that but it only work on lollipop+ version.

[TUTORIAL HERE](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-new-lollipop-activity-transitions--cms-23711)

[Custom Transition](http://cases.azoft.com/create-android-app-animations-using-transitions-api/)